# aggrid: How to set the line-height of a ag-virtual-list-item inside a sidebar filter toolpanel?

Tags: ag-grid

The line-height of a virtual item is set as element style by the agrid library. So I can't use a css class here.
I need to set a larger amount than 20px default. 
The height of the ag-virtual-list-container is obviously calculated by this amount. 
How to set another value to the line-height?

inside the sidebar ag-filter-tool-panel including 5 items:

```html
<div class="ag-virtual-list-container" style="height: 100px;">
<div class="ag-virtual-list-item" style="top: 0px; line-height: 20px;"><label class="ag-set-filter-item">
```

Comment: I have the same problem.. tried manipulating heights and line-height in various classes. But to no avail.